# Mesmo se acertar, a mensagem não muda!

Tags: python, tkinter

Eu estou tentando criar um jogo em tkinter, é coisa simples, você chuta um número e então aparece uma mensagem se o seu chute está certo ou errado. Eu já fiz isso em CLI, porém, eu fui tentar fazer uma GUI para este jogo e mesmo se você acertar o chute, ainda aparece uma mensagem de erro. Por favor, ajudem.

```
# Just some tkinter
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from random import randint as rd

class screen:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        self.frame1 = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.frame2 = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.frame1.pack()
        self.frame2.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

        self.lbl = tk.Label(self.frame1, text='Test your luck!\nPick a number!')
        self.lbl.pack()

        self.txt = tk.Entry(self.frame1)
        self.txt.get()
        self.txt.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

        self.btn = tk.Button(self.frame1, text='Send', command=self.random)
        self.btn.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

        self.lbl2 = tk.Label(self.frame2, text='')

    def random(txt):
        random_num = rd(1, 10)
        if txt == random_num:
            messagebox.showinfo('Congratulations!', 'Correct number!')
        else:
            messagebox.showerror('Error', f'Wrong number.\nCorrect number = {random_num}.')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('The Lucky Game!')
    screen(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: O `txt` dentro do método `random` é o próprio `screen`, então vc tem que pegar o valor do campo, algo como `if int(txt.txt.get()) == random_num: etc...`

Comment: @hkotsubo, posso criar uma solução com esta resposta?

Answer (score 0):

No método `random` é preciso passar a instancia da classe (um objeto) `Screen` com o `self` sendo que ela representa sua interface gráfica, e através do `self` podemos acessar a propriedade `txt` que é o campo e acessar o valor pelo método `get()` e efetuar a comparação da seguinte maneira:

```
def random(self):
    random_num = rd(1, 10)
    if int(self.txt.get()) == random_num:
        messagebox.showinfo("Congratulations!", "Correct number!")
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Wrong number.\nCorrect number = {random_num}.")
```

Vejá abaixo o comportamento que você espera da sua aplicação:

[image: tela do app para adivinhar numero]

Código da aplicação:

```
# Just some tkinter
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from random import randint as rd


class Screen:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        self.frame1 = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.frame2 = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.frame1.pack()
        self.frame2.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

        self.lbl = tk.Label(self.frame1, text='Test your luck!\nPick a number!')
        self.lbl.pack()

        self.txt = tk.Entry(self.frame1)
        self.txt.get()
        self.txt.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

        self.btn = tk.Button(self.frame1, text='Send', command=self.random)
        self.btn.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

        self.lbl2 = tk.Label(self.frame2, text='')

    def random(self):
        random_num = rd(1, 10)
        if int(self.txt.get()) == random_num:
            messagebox.showinfo('Congratulations!', 'Correct number!')
        else:
            messagebox.showerror('Error', f'Wrong number.\nCorrect number = {random_num}.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('The Lucky Game!')
    Screen(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

A resposta do usuário [@Danizavtz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/103217/danizavtz) não esta errada e aponta para o mesmo caminho que é fazer a conversão do retorno da função `get()` que é uma string para um tipo inteiro e efetuar a comparação.

Leia a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#a-simple-hello-world-program).

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado!